# Jquery - Use Variable Outside Of Function

Tags: jquery

I've read a bit and tried to figure this out but can't manage to get it to work!

The problem is that first I need to set `var count = 0;` and then count each time `$('.next')` is clicked so I can later use it at the bottom of the code and get the end variable `progress` to be correct.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 0;
    $('.next').click(function () {
        var counter = count++;
        $('.question-holder:visible').slideUp().closest('.question-holder').nextAll('.question-holder').eq(0).delay(500).slideDown();
    });
    $('.prev').click(function () {
        $('.question-holder:visible').slideUp().closest('.question-holder').prevAll('.question-holder').eq(0).delay(500).slideDown();
    });
    $('#end').on('click', function () {
        $('.question-holder').slideUp().closest('.question-holder');
        $('#end').remove();
        $('.next').remove();
        $('.prev').remove();
        $('#submit-holder').fadeIn();
    });
    var countQuestions = $('div.question-holder').length;
    var splitCount = 100 / countQuestions;
    var progress = splitCount * counter;

    $("div.bar").css("width", progress + "%");
});
```

Comment: what is the issue now ?

Comment: You increment count and you use counter. Don't use the counter variable, it's useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count` var like this -

```
var progress = splitCount * count;
```

No need for variable `counter` here `var counter = count++;`

You need `count++` only in click handler

**Edit :**

working demo -->  http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/p3PFG/2/

You need to calculate and update your progress bar inside click handler

Comment: You are a king! Thank you very very much! Really appreciate! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var count = 0;
$('.next').click(function () {
  count++;
```

...

```
var countQuestions = $('div.question-holder').length;
var splitCount = 100 / countQuestions;
var progress = splitCount * count;
```

Each time the `.click()` event is triggered, your `counter` variable is being reinitialised, hence wiping any count you are trying to keep track of.

Just increment the `count` variable and it'll work nicely.

Comment: Also, you'll need to use `count` below instead of `counter`

Comment: That question was just edited.. it was previously 'count' >.<